# Dart events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, dart, dart-js-interop

I have this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smap/XCxzK/light/), which I am converting to Dart. The problem is with the callbacks.

```
function stop(e) {
    var node = e.target.getContainer();
    node[SMap.LAYER_MARKER].style.cursor = "";
    var coords = e.target.getCoords();
    alert("Cílová pozice: " + coords.toWGS84(2).reverse().join(" "));
}

var signals = mapa.getSignals();
signals.addListener(window, "marker-drag-stop", stop);
```

My code in Dart

```
  var signals = mapa.callMethod('getSignals', []);
  signals.callMethod('addListener', [context, 'marker-drag-stop', stop]);
}


stop(MouseEvent event) {
  var target = event.target.callMethod('getContainer',[]);// problem
  context.callMethod('alert', ['texttext']); 
}
```

The stop callback is properly called, but I don't know what to do with `var node = e.target.getContainer();` line. The e.target return something, but what next.

Side question: is `mapa.callMethod('addLayer', [layer]).callMethod('enable', []);` syntax, only one posible way to call javascript methods. I find it little bit cumbersome:-/

This whole js-interop thingy is kind of messy. I'm unable to resolve it by my own and need to ask again after each step. I hope when I will cover all interop use cases, I will be able, just to use Dart and forget about JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this should do the trick:

```dart
var target = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e)['target']
  .callMethod('getContainer', []);
```

Comment: That of course worked. Have some small issue, can you tell me difference between `new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(node[layerMarker])['style']['cursor']='';` which works and `var cursor = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(node[layerMarker])['style']['cursor']; cursor='';` probably I cannot store property in variable. This one works as well `var cursor = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(node[layerMarker]);
  cursor['style']['cursor']='';`

Comment: I see no difference except that in the 2nd version a variable is created which holds a reference to `['cursor']`. If you don't need this reference later in your code you could just go with the 1st version.   If the answer solves your problem please accept it using the checkmark below the up/down-vote buttons to make it clear your question is answered.

Comment: If I assign something to the ['cursor'] reference later, it is not working. So the question was why, nevertheless I know the way around I'm just curious.

Comment: I have a troubles reading code in comments. `cursor='';` doesn`t set the `['cursor']` element in `['style']` it just assigns the empty string to the `cursor` variable. What you actually want to do is probably `var style = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(node[layerMarker])['style']; style['cursor']='';`